# Автоматическая генерация свойств класса

Tags: c#

Привет, ХэшКод. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно добавить свойства классу в рантайме? К примеру, я получаю на вход Dictionary или HashTable и из ключей, которые в них есть, сгенерировать свойства, которые возвращали бы значения ключей. Возможно ли такое? Спасибо.

Comment: только если использовать `dynamic`

Comment: Свойств, зачем это может понадобится? А обращаться потом к ним как, через рефлексию? Мне кажется максимум, что вы сможете сделать это переопределить индексатор

Comment: @Spectre, спасибо, и я хоть почитаю про ваш шарп. (хотя реализация того, что хочет ТС мне пока не понятна, расскажите :) )

Comment: Лично я бы добавил нужный метод в Ваш класс, а если класс не самописный, то использовал бы методы-расширения. Ну а если Вас и это не устроит, то рекомендую пересмотреть архитектуру Вашего приложения.

Comment: Кхм, всем спасибо за ответы и коментарии, видимо, я, совсем погорячился с идеями. Буду обращаться просто по ключу и не выдумывать лишнего :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Динамическое добавление свойств достаточно трудоемкий процесс, использующий .NET3.0. Как уже было замечено, обращаться затем через рефлексию к методам тоже тяжело. Язык С# строго типизирован, хотя наблюдается некоторое смещение акцента в последнее время. Если вас еще интересует, то посмотрите в сторону ExpandObject. Вот небольшая ссылка на [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740021/how-to-dynamic-new-anonymous-class)

Comment: *Акцент нельзя сместить.* `C#` как был статически типизированным языком со строгой типизацией, так и остался, а `dynamic` - просто синтаксический сахар.

Comment: я бы не сказал, что DLR это синтаксический сахар

Comment: @Spectre Ну, я конечно утрирую, но просто мне кажется, что добавление `Object'у` специального набора метаданных и методов для работы с этим набором не стоит называть *смещением акцентов.*

Comment: Все таки, [`DLR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052.aspx)  - это не тоже самое, что и `ExpandoObject`. Runtime, через который который может интерпретироваться такой динамический язык, как `python`, явно нечто большее, чем просто синтаксический сахар.

Хотя, я думаю, назвать появление `DLR` смещением акцентов *`C#`* тоже не верно. Скорее уж всей платформы `.NET` в целом, а не `C#`.

Comment: да, это не из-за того, что модно, это скорее необходимость. Строгая типизация так и останется преоритетом мне кажется

Answer (score 1):

А где Вы это собираетесь использовать? Если с компонентами вроде `PropertyGrid`, то реализуйте в Вашем объекте `ICustomTypeDescriptor`.